# Routing Docker in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, docker, routing, ifconfig

In my routing table on Ubuntu 18.04 I have these entries:

```
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9f3f970041e3
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-66d1d4ca46a2
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

The docker0 entry I managed to move to a different IP range by creating a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file and adding `{"bip": "172.19.0.1/16"}` to it.

I'm not sure where the `br-*` entries come from but I know that if I remove them that Docker stops working so they are used by Docker.

I need to have Docker assign these `br-*` addresses at `172.20.0.0` and `172.21.0.0` because the corp network uses the ones that they are currently occupying.

Questions:

1. What part of Docker is creating these `br-*` entries?
2. How does Docker use these entries?
3. How can I configure Docker to assign them to other ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker uses bridges to split the network into several isolate parts. `br-*` usually are created with `docker-compose` files when you run your containers with a compose file (`docker-compose.yml`). so docker creates a new network bridge to isolate your container. you can see your networks with this:

```
docker network ls
```

**output:**

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
78d5fd93be37        bridge                 bridge              local
b20b47d754cd        example1_default       bridge              local
f26798e4e71c        exporter-net           bridge              local
ed99a6f6dfc1        host                   host                local
12910824ac92        none                   null                local
```

`br-*` bridges come from `br-<NETWORK ID>` of your networks.

you can see its subnet and the containers using this network with the command:

```
docker inspect <NETWORK NAME like example1_default>
```

**output:**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "example1_default",
        "Id": "b20b47d754cdaba5dfe89f181e5d5a93eee4c50d3f34d8d93f16eed2e80e72b0",
        "Created": "2019-05-12T18:16:03.618737845+04:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16", ##### subnet
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": { ##### containers using this network
            "5a3fba164f7c15318eaab64b65a1c7996a1da15d84629e818e8b61195fe14345": {
                "Name": "example_container",
                "EndpointID": "cbced3c6c8ae79ae266261de6f62f469aefdc6a7a0f5f79fd0f04301f0030e34",
                "MacAddress": "03:11:fe:00:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "example1"
        }
    }
]
```

to change this subnet range, you must create a new network with custom subnet:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.123.123.0/24 new_network
```

and reconnect your containers to the new network. you must repeat this for all containers using the old_network.

```
docker network disconnect old_network container_name
docker network connect new_network container_name
```

Now you can remove old_network and use the ranges.